# Share url in Whatsapp via web site

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, whatsapp

I've been trying for a while build some method to share information from my web page via the Whatsapp application.

I actually found an easy method to do it using this code:

```
  <div class="outer-div">
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text=.../">
         <img src="partager.png">
    </a>
  </div>
```

it works great, but i still don't find how to know if the user really shared the information, or just got back to the web page.
I still don't find a way to validate if the information was shared or not. 
With how many people did the information shared ?

I searched in the internet but i didn't find any API to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I don't think this is possible, this is because to do this successfully there would be the need for communication of WhatsApp and the user's browser which you have no control over using Intent or some api.